# Httpclient Slow Performance same computer Android Emulator Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I am using the HttpClient but my results are taking up to 6 seconds coming back from the same machine on the same subnet and ip range of 192.168. When I call the api directly from the ip address the results are more or less instant so why is it so slow with httpclient on the same computer.

I have seen other so's that suggest set to use proxy as false is the best way to go.

I have also tested this on a stock phone and it takes around 8 seconds for the login to be successful on the phone.

```
private HttpClient _client;
public async Task<String> Getusers()
{
        var content = "";
        HttpClientHandler hch = new HttpClientHandler();
        hch.Proxy = null;
        hch.UseProxy = false;
        _client = new HttpClient(hch);
        var uri = new Uri(Constants.ApiEndPoint + "/Users"); // Your url is here

        try
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return content;
}
```

Here is my login method in case anyone can see something wrong with it.

```
private async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string content = await Getusers(); //Sends a GET request to the specified Uri and returns the response body as a string in an asynchronous operation
    List<Users> _users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(content); //Deserializes or converts JSON String into a collection of Post
    var userName = txtUserName.Text;
    var password = txtPassword.Text;
    var isValidUser = _users.Where(w => w.UserName == userName && w.password == password).FirstOrDefault();
    var driverId = _users.Where(w => w.UserName == userName && w.password == password).FirstOrDefault().ID;         


    if (isValidUser != null)
    {

            Application.Current.Properties["driverId"] = driverId;
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
    else
    {
            lblError.Text = "Error your credentials are invalid, please try again";
    }         

  }
```

Comment: 1) Use `HttpClient` in a singleton pattern. 2) Have you tried it NOT using the Android emulator (notoriously slow) and a physical Android device instead?

Comment: Assuming you are using an emulator/simulator - I would not do any performance analysis on the emulator/simulator.

Comment: @Jason it  also takes about 8 seconds via wifi on a phone.

Comment: @Jason I have enclosed my example login button code in case anything performance wise could be slowing it down.

Comment: @rogue39nin Are you benchmarking just the http call, or the entire `BtnLogin_Clicked` method... ? Is this a release build or a debug build? Are you XAML page(s) (`MainPage`) compiled via XAMLC?

Comment: @SushiHangover just the http client call it shouldnt take 8 seconds to grab the data.

Comment: @Have you actually profiled it? Also is that the first call to httpclient? (i.e. are all the dependent assemblies loading for the first time during that call?) Are you using the Mono HttpClient handler or the Android client handler (in the Android build settings) Also you are benchmarking a debug or release build? If release, are you AOTing the assemblies?

Comment: @SushiHangover on release it appears to take longer i am using xamrian forms version of the httpclient?.

Comment: in your Android project settings you can choose which underlying http provider is used by HttpClient

Comment: Default httpclient in xamarin xamarin forms is too slow. Try using moderhttpclient-updated nugget.

Comment: @KaranRami Hi what tests have you done to prove this is there article recomendation for this.

Comment: @rogue39nin i have faced same issue with default httpclient. and after using that nuget i got 40% improvement in my API calls. refering this thread will give you more info about it https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31770/your-experiences-with-modernhttpclient

Comment: @KaranRami its quite an old project looks like no longer maintained by the user.

Comment: @rogue39nin here is updated one, https://github.com/alexrainman/ModernHttpClient. Atleast give it a try and you can modify it as per you requirements in future.

Comment: @KaranRami have done still the same issues slow speed on http

Comment: @KaranRami I have now got it into xamrian's bug list https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/projects/3#card-20974258 as they can replicate it but god knows how long this will take them to patch.

Comment: @rogue39nin good to know that. I wish they improve it. Native apps are much faster than xamarin forms app when making API calls.

Comment: @KaranRami when you say native do you mean an ordinary native xamrian andriod app is faster?

Comment: @rogue39nin no, i mean pure Android and pure iOS