# Xamarin and TLS1.3

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am performing an HttpClient for a website with TLS1.3.
On my main phone as well as on the emulator, it runs smoothly.
In an old cell phone (Android 6.0) that I have for testing, it takes absurd 2min15sec.
Is there anything I can do to improve this performance?

[image]

Comment: TLS 1.3 is used by default in Android 10 for all TLS . So on such an old version it will be an expected result . Check https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#tls-1.3

Comment: I can understand, but I can't accept it.
If I access the site using Chrome, I don't have this problem.
There must be something that can be done to at least lessen the problem.

Comment: Consider testing the website with a native Android demo if possible, if native is also not performing well, then not much we can do. If native is rather quick, consider giving a try to this nuget: https://github.com/alexrainman/ModernHttpClient as people claims it helps to improve the performance(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894813/httpclient-slow-performance-same-computer-android-emulator-xamarin).